# Где хранятся переменные объекты в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Где хранятся переменные в JavaScript?

Например, если мы напишем объект:

```
let menu = {...}
```

то где это хранится?

В `JAVA'е` когда мы создаем объект оно хранится в `HEAP`.

Comment: Вообще говоря стандарт языка JS не регламентирует где хранить переменные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные в JavaScript храниться в памяти браузерного процесса, если упростить то можно сказать что они хранятся в RAM.

Но поскольку cookie тоже могут считаться переменными, то конкретно они
сохраняться в постоянной памяти устройства (HDD, SSD, и т.п.).

Так же RAM может быть [временно перенесена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) в постоянную память устройства для оптимизации работы последнего.

---

Как и в большинстве других языков программирования, то что необходимо для выполнения конкретной функции, например контекст, будет сохранено в stack'e, остальное же будет храниться в heap.

Comment: Кажется, вопрос был о том, в какой именно части RAM - в стеке или куче?

Comment: А ещё любое содержимое RAM всегда может быть отправлено на HDD, так как виртуальную память и файл подкачки никто не отменял

Comment: а если объявим так let s = "hello"; оно идет в String pool?

Comment: @Agata, концепт `string pool` не присутствует в JS в том виде, в котором он реализован в Java.